What is the difference between GTest printing "[passed]" and the checkmark icon in Test Explorer?
I have a GoogleTest TEST that Visual Studio reports as Failed in the Test Explorer, accompanied by a round red icon with an X in the middle, making it pretty clear that the test has failed.

However, when I click on that entry in the Test Explorer, and view the output of that test, it all looks reasonable and ends with
[       OK ] PaperWithdrawalStrategyTestDebug.canCreateTestFixtureMembers3 (1344 ms)
[----------] 1 test from PaperWithdrawalStrategyTestDebug (1344 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (1344 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.

Does [ PASSED ] here contradict the icon, or do they have distinct meanings? What is the difference?

I am aware that an MCVE is missing to debug this. I don't have one yet. I'd just like to know whether this is a bug or whether I am misunderstanding something.

Further Observations
I have since writing the question noticed that the test consistently is reported as successful when I click Debug instead of Run, although both run in debug mode. And with the same test outputs being printed in both cases. So I am starting to be confident that this is simply a bug in visual studio.

Show the complete gtest run output. The answer can be after [  PASSED  ].

@3CxEZiVlQ [ PASSED ] is the last line. Before the pasted snippet there is the expected test output, including a gmock warning about an uninteresting mock function call.

I have since writing the question noticed that the test consistently is reported as successful when I click Debug instead of Run, although both run in debug mode. And with the same test outputs being printed in both cases. So I am starting to be confident that this is simply a bug in visual studio.
